# Swift: How would you filter through an array dropdown as you type into a text field?

Tags: swift

I have a text field where when you start typing a dropdown appears with an array of products that the user can pre-select to fill in the field. What I am trying to do is filter the array as the user types so that if the user types the letter f only products with that letter appear and so on and so forth. How would I filter through the array as the user types? The dropdown is a tableview and each product is in a tableview row.

[image]

Comment: What did you try?